# fixed point function (nonlinear equation)

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

here's the following problem, I'm trying to find a real root by fixed-point iteration method but I can't find a properly $g(x)$ that meets the condition that $|g'(x_0)|<1$.
 Well, my nonlinear equation is $f(x)=1.08^x-\frac{125}{81}=0$ so I add +x in both sides, $g(x)=1.08^x-\frac{125}{81}+x=x$ but when I do $g'(x) =d/dx(1.08^x - 125/81 + x) = 0.076961*1.08^x + 1$ and I try to solve inequality to know a initial value $x_0$ I got this after set this equation $g'(x)=0.076961*1.08^x + 1 < 1$: $Im(x) = (π (2 n + 1))/(3 log(3) - 2 log(5))$,$n \in Z $ .
PS: My real root of $x \approx 5.637457293$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have $x + \text{increasing-function-of-$x$}$, obviously you're going to get $1 + \text{positive-value}$ as the derivative, which will therefore not satisfy the condition. So shift everything over to the right side and take $g(x) = x - 1.08^x + \frac{125}{81}$.

Comment: Thank you, it works on my code ;). By the way, is there a general way to find $g(x)$ ?

Comment: I know of no such method (this is not really my area of study, so someone better might actually know some systematic or semi-systematic way). That might very well be a deficiency of the method that makes others like Newton-Raphson method superior to it.

Comment: The solution is indeed $\ln(125/81)/\ln 1.08\approx5.6374572930016$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling

$$
f(x) = a^x-b
$$

we have

$$
f(x)= f(x_k) + f'(x_k)(x-x_k) + O(|x-x_k|^2)
$$

so with $x$ near a root we have

$$
f(x)\approx 0 = f(x_k)+f'(x_k)(x-x_k)
$$

thus

$$
x = x_{k+1} = x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}  
$$

now calling $g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ we have

$$
x_{k+1} = g(x_k)\\
x_k = g(x_{k-1})
$$

and

$$
x_{k+1}-x_k = g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1})
$$

but

$$
g(x_k) = g(x_{k-1})+g'(x_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})+O(|x_k-x_{k-1}|^2)
$$

or

$$
x_{k+1}-x_k = g'(x_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})+O(|x_k-x_{k-1}|^2)
$$

now assuming small $O(|x_k-x_{k-1}|^2)$ we can assure convergence if $|g'(x)| < 1$ at the root vicinity.

In our case we have

$$
g(x) = x-\frac{a^x-b}{a^x\ln a}
$$

and for convergence (sufficient) we need $|g'(x)| = |1-b a^{-x}|< 1$